# gitignore not working for process.env in my backend folder

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` looks like the following

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

I have a `process.env` file located in the root of my `backend` folder but `gitignore` does not ignore `process.env`. `gitignore` ignores `node_modules` so why is `process.env` being tracked?

My [github](https://github.com/develijahlee/quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is being tracked because at some point in the history, you told Git to track it, either explicitly or with `git add .`.  Because you did that, and the file was not in `.gitignore` at the time, it was added and tracked.

From the file you've shown us, I see no reason it should be ignored; there are clearly no entries which match `process.env`.

If your question is why your `.gitignore` does not contain a rule to omit it, then the answer is because nobody has added an entry.  It looks like you've used a template version from GitHub, which is generally fine, but of course different projects have different needs and you're expected to edit the file to meet your own project's needs.

If you don't want it to be tracked in future revisions, run `git rm --cached process.env` and then add an appropriate entry to `.gitignore`, then commit those two changes.